# Conversion of Special characters from MS-Word or Open Office writer to Notepad

Tags: c#, gembox-spreadsheet

I have a string and I am using GEMBOX SPREADSHEET

```
string sr = “Save as type”;
```

In this  -- Save as type --  is normal string but when i am  loading a Text file Using GEMBOX

this Symbol

```
“Save as type”
```

is Converted to

```
�Save as type�
```

How to solve this Issue ? This is the Code comes when i try to Implement that

```
65533
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the following function to replace the special Word/Excel characters when you parse the data from the worksheets:

```
public static string ReplaceWordChars(this string text)
{
    var s = text;

    s = Regex.Replace(s, "[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]", "'"); // smart single quotes and apostrophe
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]", "\""); // smart double quotes
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "\u2026", "..."); // ellipsis
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "[\u2013|\u2014]", "-"); // dashes
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "\u02C6", "^"); // circumflex
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "\u2039", "<"); // open angle bracket
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "\u203A", ">"); // close angle bracket
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "[\u02DC|\u00A0]", " "); // spaces

    return s;
}
```

This function does not replace all special characters, but only the most common ones used by Word/Excel.

I recently had the same problem while working on a webservice project, and came across this function during a Google search. This is the original article where I found the code: http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Replace-MS-Word-special-characters-in-javascript-and-C.aspx

Comment: I'm using that code from that site as well but have raised a query with the author. \u02DC is a tilde according to http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2dc/index.htm and indeed typing ALT+732 in Word gives a tilde.