# Convert text to plain text inside textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, textbox

I have an app that has a textbox, validation control and a button. The problem is that if someone copies text from a word document inside the textbox, some of the special characters won't be allowed because of the validation control. But if I delete those special characters and we typed them, the validation control works. Is there a way to convert that text to plain text or rich text inside the textbox?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following. It seems like the validation control is doing what it is supposed to do. What's the problem? Can you provide some code/an example of how it's supposed to behave?

Comment: Okay, so say I copy something from word that has an apostrophe(') in it, but since it from word document, the formatting of the apostrophe is not the standard apostrophe on the keyboard. Thus, I want to convert all special characters to standard keyboard characters. Not the very rich characters that word sometimes have. Does that explain it a little better?

Comment: Somewhat better but "standard keyboard characters" is not well-defined. (Are these characters that I'm typing okay? 1ºÑ—»½©¿¾Éõ…) Also, perhaps you don't want validation but just input "sanitizing" instead, whatever that means in your app.

Comment: No, standard keyboard characters ( US keyboard layout) that you just have to push one or two buttons, without using "alt" key and number pad (no ASCII OCT codes). And I have some of that, but to better secure the app, you can't catch all threats with sanitizing: some characters, it's just better not to allow than to filter them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to convert the text to plain ASCII before you do the validation.

Check out this answer: [Conversion of Special characters from MS-Word or Open Office writer to Notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878224/conversion-of-special-characters-from-ms-word-or-open-office-writer-to-notepad)

It looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: I ended up just adding some of these MS-Word characters to the validation control. But I like these answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it's a winforms application:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

> ```
> public class MyTextBox : TextBox 
> {
>     protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {        
>         if (m.Msg == 0x302 && Clipboard.ContainsText())
>         {          
>             var text = new string(Clipboard.GetText().Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());
>             this.SelectedText = text;
>             return;
>         }
>         base.WndProc(ref m);
>     }
> }
> ```

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18zw7440(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp

Comment: Not winforms app. Web app. that's what that tag is for ("asp.net")